# Dealing with a constant in an indefinite integral when solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am going through the simplest example of a differential equation (Tenenbaum & Pollard - Ordinary Differential Equations)

Let $x$ denote the amount of carbon in a tree, i.e. amount of $C^{14}$. Then we can express the rate at which this quantity declines with the following equation, intuitively

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx$$

So, off the bat. I don't like this notation. From it, it is not clear that the amount of carbon in a tree is a function of time. Technically, there is no problem with that notation. It can be interpreted as ratio that is small change in carbon divided by small change in time = minus times some constant times the amount of carbon in a tree at that time. All is well.

But then, proper notation abuse, in my view, happens

$$\frac{dx}{x} = -k dt$$

if I could tolerate the above equation, this is too much for me. So this led me to solving the first equation, my way

First, I define a function $f(t)$, for a value of time $t$ it will output the amount of carbon in a tree. So effectively $f(t) = x_t$

Now that I have improved the notation, re-write the original equation

$$\frac{df(t)}{dt} = -k f(t)$$

Let's proceed by integrating

$$\int \frac{df(t)}{dt} dt = -k \int f(t) dt$$

$$f(t) = -k \int f(t) dt$$

Now we ask ourselves what function could satisfy this, exponential!

But, this is where I have a bit of a problem:

(i) what do I do with a constant that comes out of the integral on the RHS, i.e. $-k \int f(t) dt = -k * (\text{integral of} f(t) + c)$

(ii) where to use my initial boundary condition. In that at time 0 the amount of carbon can be set to 1 to represent 100% has to be somehow tied to (i)

Comment: reason for the down-vote would be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx \tag 1$$
You wrote :

But then, proper notation abuse, in my view, happens
$$\frac{dx}{x} = -k\, dt \tag 2$$
if I could tolerate the above equation, this is too much for me.

(End of citation).

The question is "What is too much for you ? "

First : Is it because from Eq.$(1)$ you don't accept
$$dx=-k\,x\, dt \tag 3$$
A small variation $dx$ is proportional to $x$ and proportional to the small laps of time $dt$ during this variation occurs. This is the mathematical model of the physical phenomena. Nothing more.

Are you troubled by what looks like a division by $dt$ to go from $(3)$ to $(1)$ ?

Refer to the definition of the derivative of a function with regards to a variable.

It has long been recognised that notations $(1)$ and $(3)$ are correct and they are commonly used by Physicists. If you don't like it on theoretical sens you should refer to the Non Standard Analysis which pooves this is valid on purely mathematical bases.

Second: Is it because one divide $(3)$ by $x$ and this division isn't acceptable in case of $x=0$ ?

Obviously in the present case $x$ is never equal to $0$. Since $x$ denote the amount of $C^{14}$ in a tree there is allways a non nul amont of $C^{14}$ (at least one atom, but not $0$).

Thus notations in Eq.$(2)$ are not at all abuse.

Third : It is easy to avoid Eq.$(2)$ with a change of variable.

Since $x> 0\:$ let
$$x(t)=e^{u(t)} \quad ; \quad \frac{dx}{dt}=e^u\frac{du}{dt}=x\frac{du}{dt}$$
From Eq.$(1)$ :
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x\frac{du}{dt}=-k\,x$$
$x\neq 0$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-k$$
$$u=-kt+c$$
$$x(t)=e^{-kt+c}=C\:e^{-kt}$$

Comment: my main issue is this Leibniz notation. He conjured this up when thinking from the infinitesimals pov. Then, centuries later, everyone agreed that his notation is powerful, so they came up with limits and now we had rigorous proofs that did not require resorting to infinitesimals that don't belong in reals. Why am I saying all of this? It is because when you think about that derivative from the limits pov, then it is not a ratio. But, we can prove that what we did there (i.e. divided by dx and divided by dt) is OK. My dissonance is that I have to keep this in my mind, but know that if

Comment: I do something too weird, at some point (by treating the derivative as a ratio), it may bite me, and I won't even know it. Thank you for your answer! Very extensive and useful for me.

Comment: Treating the derivative as a ration has long been a theoretical debate between Mathematiciens and Physisists. I think that nowadays the difficulty is overcome thanks to NSA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis . Presently the difficulty is to understand and accept it. If it was easy  the question would have been solved much sooner. I am afraid that there is no elementary way to teach it. An article for the general public  : https://fr.scribd.com/document/14755203/Une-querelle-des-Anciens-et-des-Modernes is easy to read (in French) but oversimplified.